# Left join statement has no column 'client'

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am trying to append a column to the right

```
SELECT
  'abc' as client,
  sum(nested.freq) as freq,
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      uh.route
      COUNT(uh.route) as freq
    FROM
      employee AS up,
      hist AS uh
    where
      up.id = uh.eID
      AND uh.PrhEEBankRoute = '123'
    GROUP BY
      uh.route
  ) AS nested
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      'abc' as client,
      sum(raw.freq) as total_trans
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          uh.route,
          COUNT(uh.route) as freq
        FROM
        employee AS up,
        hist AS uh

        where
          up.id = uh.eID
        GROUP BY
          uh.route
      ) AS raw
  ) raw2 ON raw2.client = nested.client;
```

The expected result is something like this

```
client | freq | total_trans
abc   | 2  | 100
```

But I am getting the following error:

> left join statement has no column 'client'

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: The error that there is no column client when I try to run this sql statement

Comment: Well yes, `nested.client;` doesn't exist, because you don't have a column in your first select called `client`. And you are missing a comma between `SELECT uh.route COUNT`. And you have an additional comma `as freq,`. So basically a whole bunch of syntax errors that you could find yourself in SSMS. BTW best practice is "proper" joins, not comma separated implicit joins.

Comment: Also [SQL Server 2008 is out of support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/troubleshoot/sql/general/end-support-sql-server-2008) for almost two years (or even exactly two years to the day -- unfortunately Microsoft doesn't use unambiguous date formats but this BS ??/??/YYYY, even in translations to languages that don't know such a format at all...). Consider upgrading soon.

Comment: Evolve! No one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). This is made worse by using both join styles. And note that all references to "client" are literals - so joining on that column alone is logically a cross join if those joins were syntactically correct. I suggest you start over.

Comment: `left join statement has no column 'client'` this is the actual error message ? ? Are you using `SQL Server` ?

Answer (score 1):

The first subquery, aliased as "nested" is:

```
SELECT
       uh.route                 --<< no column called "client" 
     , COUNT(uh.route) AS freq  --<< no column called "client" 
FROM employee AS up
    , hist AS uh
WHERE up.id = uh.eID
    AND uh.PrhEEBankRoute = '123'
GROUP BY uh.route
```

In the next subquery at the join condition you refer to nested.client

```
) raw2 ON raw2.client = nested.client;
```

That column does not exist in the nested subquery, so the error message is accurate.